# execution plan question

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have this query running for long time

```
    (@P0 nvarchar(4000))

select emaildmo0_.Id as Id7_
    ,emaildmo0_.CreatedDate as CreatedD2_7_
    ,emaildmo0_.EmailAddress as EmailAdd3_7_
    ,emaildmo0_.EmailType_Id as EmailType4_7_
    ,emaildmo0_.isPreferedEmail as isPrefer5_7_
    ,emaildmo0_.ProfileId as ProfileId7_
    ,emaildmo0_.UpdatedDate as UpdatedD6_7_
from dbo.Email emaildmo0_
where emaildmo0_.EmailAddress = @P0
```

This is the execution plan

[image]

My first question why it is index scan not index seek

These 2 lines from the ExecutionPlan.xml

```
        <Warnings>
          <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(255),[emaildmo0_].[EmailAddress],0)" />
          <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Seek Plan" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(255),[emaildmo0_].[EmailAddress],0)=[@P0]" />
        </Warnings>
```

May you explain for me what is this warning mean ? and if there is any suggestion to tune this query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the parameter should be defined to match the data type of the underlying column - currently the parameter is nvarchar(4000) but it should be varchar (looks like 255 but you should check the table).

Whether this actually makes your query slow or leads to a bad plan is tougher to determine. But making those two definitions match certainly isn't going to make it worse.

If you can't change the parameter data type, either get a better ORM or change the column as a last resort.